# undefined symbol _main in module c0.ASM

Tags: c

This program is being compiled successfully but giving following linking error :

undefined symbol _main in module c0.ASM

My program is following :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
char input[] = "hello sumit kumar";
char *a;
a = input;
printf("%s", a);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Remove the #include<conio.h> and replace getch to getchar.

Comment: This is a linker error, and depends on how you compile and link the program. The C code itself is correct, assuming you are using Windows.

Comment: Since the error seems not to be in the code you have shown, you need to give details about how you build and link the project. What environment, such as Visual Studio or GCC, are you using? What kind of project have you created? How do you build it?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are on linux: The following program would work.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[] = "hello sumit kumar"; //Removed stray marks at the beginning
    char *a;
    a = input;
    printf("%s", a);
    getchar();   //To use getch() have to include <curses.h> file
    return 0; //Removed stray marks at the end
}
```

Comment: Given that he includes conio.h, it is probably the Windows getch he meant, not the curses one.

Comment: @GirjeshShakya Tested the same on Linux PC, working fine. Same should work in other OS's also. What environment do you use?

Comment: @SantoshA I am using turbo c++

Comment: @GirjeshShakya change `main()` to `main(void)` and try